# Symfony Elasticsearch configuration file is not working with 1 index for multiple types

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have the following configuration in my **config.yml**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:      
        app:
            finder: ~            
            types:
                product:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                        sku: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                stock:
                    properties:
                        sku: ~
                        stock: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductStock
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

**Error**

> Rejecting mapping update to [app] as the final mapping would have more
>   than 1 type: [stock, product]

If I check the documentation I see the following on there Github page [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/cookbook/multi-type-search.md)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a a fault of Symfony integration. Reason is removal of support of multiple types per index [introduced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) by Elasticsearch back in 6.0. You need to update your index definition to only have single type of data per index.

Comment: Thx, for your answer so i need to create a unique index for each of them? But how can I combine them if there are multiple index and not just 1 ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create separate index for each type of data. Access to multiple indexes is allowed by using wildcards, please refer [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html).

Comment: and how can I join the results of these two indexes in 1 results. Currently they giving two results separate.

Comment: Joins are not a natural thing in Elasticsearch, it is a mistake to treat Elasticsearch in the same way as relational database. Elasticsearch have support for [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) but it is quite specific and is not something that is directly related to joins in RDBMS

Comment: What's the best approach? Stock is related to Product but it's not the same table. How should I treat them? Could you advise me?

Comment: It really depends on what queries you will need to run against these types of data. Elasticsearch is not a general purpose solution, it is mainly search engine, so depending on your goals best choice may be to use database as main storage and Elasticsearch for certain parts of it (e.g. for searching, advanced aggregation and analysis and other areas where Elasticsearch shines)

Comment: Thx, but i'm new into the Elasticsearch so i need advise if you could help me it will be appreciated. I have 1m+ products and every product has a minimum of 5-12 vendors with their stock information etc. If we want to order we will use a search to find the information. So in my case i'm not 100% sure to use Elastichsearch or the old fashion way queries. Elasticsearch is providing me the results really fast, but to achieve my goal i have to create my own join method.

Comment: In your case it looks like you need to take a look at [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype to store vendors list for product. But vendors list itself needs to stay into separate index and there will be no relationships (and hence guaranteed consistency) between these indexes. If you need guaranteed data consistency - you need to switch to RDBMS